# Cron not doing my task without the command python manage.py runcrons

Tags: python, django, django-cron

I managed to make a function that sends lots of emails to every user in my Django application, for that I used the django-cron package.

I need to send the emails in a particular hour of the day, so I added in my function the following:

```
RUN_AT_TIMES = ['14:00']

schedule = Schedule(run_at_times=RUN_AT_TIMES)
```

The problem is that this function is only called if I run the command:

```
python manage.py runcrons
```

What can I do to make the application work after one single call of the command `python manage.py runcrons`?

P.S.: I need this application to work in Heroku as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the docs' [installation guide](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) at point 6, you need to set up a cron job to execute the command. The packages takes away the annoyance of setting up separate cron jobs for all your commands, but does not eliminate cron entirely.

EDIT: after seeing your update, as I understand working with crons on heroku depends on plan (really not sure about that), but there are some apps that help with that. [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) for example.

Comment: Got it, but how can I do this?